# Laravel get value by month

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get a value (sum) called `billable` by `month`.

I've tried it like this:

```
$time = Ride::where('date', '>=', Carbon::now()->firstOfYear())
                    ->select('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m") as month, sum(billabletime) as time')
                    ->groupBy('month')
                    ->pluck('time');
```

But when I do it like this I receive:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DATE_FORMAT(date,' in 'field list' (SQL: select `DATE_FORMAT(date,` as `as` from `ride` where `date` >= 2016-01-01 00:00:00 group by `month`)
```

How do I get this to work (I use mysql)?

Comment: Use `select(DB::raw(...))` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
->select(\DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%m") as month, sum(billabletime) as time'))
```

Laravel is putting backticks around `DATE_FORMAT` so SQL thinks it's a column.  Use `DB::raw()` function to get around this.

Comment: @jamie Awesome, glad to hear it.  If you found this useful, please be sure to accept my answer.